# how to create a macro containing all possible unsigned characters inside a string?

Tags: c, macros, ascii

I want to have a macro that can be edited with ease in my header that will define a string containing all the unsigned characters

my first thoughts were something like:

```
#define MYSTRING "\
a\
b\
c\
d\
ect...\
"
```

and the user could comment out the characters they didn't want inside the string. The problem is I don't know how to represent all 255 unsigned characters and I feel like there should be a way to represent them using their actual ascii values, but I don't know how.

EDIT: ok so I realize this may not be a good way since you actually cannot comment out lines inside quotes...

open to alternatives though!

Comment: This **must** be an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve with this? It's not defined how many valid characters there are, btw.

Comment: The "commenting out" part itself seems a challenge.

Comment: somewhere in my program I am checking to see if a character is in the character set the user has set. I am using strchr to check

Comment: Hint hint, you don't need to use a macro for that.

Comment: And you do so by searching for the given character in the string you are trying to macro-define?

Comment: @Yunnosch hmm you are right, and yes the user is supposed to define the set of characters the program will check in

Comment: How exactly are you planning to handle “œ”? (or the more general question, are you sure your text actually only has ASCII characters in ASCII encoding?)

Comment: The set of values an `unsigned char` can represent are numerically `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`  (where `UCHAR_MAX`, defined in `<limits.h>`, is equal to `255` or more).   Although it is not possible to create the complete set of values with a macro, a loop can easily iterate over values from `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`.

Comment: How will the user "define the set of characters the program will check in" if it is hard coded in the source code?

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah as yunnosch pointed out my original plan to let them comment out the characters they didn't want will not work

Comment: When you say "user", you are probably not referring to an actual "user", but a developer using your code?

Comment: @groo correct, probably future me (im like 100% sure no developer wants that code :P)

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess the role "user" OP mentions, is called "integrator" in many environments (e.g. where I work). I.e. somebody editing a configuation-header to adapt to UseCase, before building.

Comment: A configuration file opened at run time might be the way to go (with numerical values?).